# Hide WooCommerce product if already purchased by logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am creating an LMS using LearnDash + WooCommerce. So far so good. Now, I'd like to hide a Product when the logged-in user has already purchased it to a) prevent the user from purchasing it twice, and b) so that I can display a product grid for them *without* the already purchased item(s).

Another example: if a user who purchased ITEM A goes to the shop, ITEM A should not even be displayed for them.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up with a nice workaround:

On the product page, I created a CUSTOM FIELD where I can input the COURSE ID.

Then, with PHP, I check the Product and retrieve the custom field for the COURSE ID.

LearnDash has a shortcode for students... so after retrieving the course ID, I can display a message/button for users who have registered already for this course.

This is the code:

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $postid = $product->get_id();
    $courseid = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'ID_del_curso', true );
    $html = '"]<center><div class="alreadyPurchased"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap paddingRightM"></i> Ya te has registrado</div></center>';
    $openIT = '[student course_id="';
    $closeIT = '[/student]';
    echo do_shortcode( $openIT . $courseid . $html . $closeIT ); 
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler solution.
Use this LearnDash shortcode...

[visitor]
Hello visitor.
Put your "Buy now" button here.
[/visitor]

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Disables repeat purchase for products / variations
 * 
 * @param bool $purchasable true if product can be purchased
 * @param \WC_Product $product the WooCommerce product
 * @return bool $purchasable the updated is_purchasable check
 */
function sv_disable_repeat_purchase( $purchasable, $product ) {

    // Don't run on parents of variations,
    // function will already check variations separately
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        return $purchasable;
    }

    // Get the ID for the current product (passed in)
    $product_id = $product->get_id(); 

    // return false if the customer has bought the product / variation
    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $product_id ) ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'sv_disable_repeat_purchase', 10, 2 );


/**
 * Shows a "purchase disabled" message to the customer
 */
function sv_purchase_disabled_message() {
    global $product; // get the current product to see if it has been purchased

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {

        foreach ( $product->get_children() as $variation_id ) {
            // Render the purchase restricted message if it has been purchased
            if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $variation_id ) ) {
                sv_render_variation_non_purchasable_message( $product, $variation_id );
            }
        }

    } else {

        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) {
            echo '<div class="woocommerce"><div class="woocommerce-info wc-nonpurchasable-message">You\'ve already purchased this product! It can only be purchased once.</div></div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'sv_purchase_disabled_message', 31 );


/**
 * Generates a "purchase disabled" message to the customer for specific variations
 * 
 * @param \WC_Product $product the WooCommerce product
 * @param int $no_repeats_id the id of the non-purchasable product
 */
function sv_render_variation_non_purchasable_message( $product, $no_repeats_id ) {

    // Double-check we're looking at a variable product
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && $product->has_child() ) {

        $variation_purchasable = true;

        foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {

            // only show this message for non-purchasable variations matching our ID
            if ( $no_repeats_id === $variation['variation_id'] ) {
                $variation_purchasable = false; 
                echo '<div class="woocommerce"><div class="woocommerce-info wc-nonpurchasable-message js-variation-' . sanitize_html_class( $variation['variation_id'] ) . '">You\'ve already purchased this product! It can only be purchased once.</div></div>';
            }
        }
    }

    if ( ! $variation_purchasable ) {
        wc_enqueue_js("
            jQuery('.variations_form')
                .on( 'woocommerce_variation_select_change', function( event ) {
                    jQuery('.wc-nonpurchasable-message').hide();
                })
                .on( 'found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
                    jQuery('.wc-nonpurchasable-message').hide();
                    if ( ! variation.is_purchasable ) {
                        jQuery( '.wc-nonpurchasable-message.js-variation-' + variation.variation_id ).show();
                    }
                })
            .find( '.variations select' ).change();
        ");
    }
}
```

Gist snippet got from [here](https://gist.github.com/bekarice/a2da034d37dbc64d41be) - please check

Comment: hey thanks so much for this! it's not exactly what I'm trying to do. I would like the product to be hidden for any user who has already purchased it. for example, if they go to the All Products page, the purchased product should not even appear on the list. Can this be done?